# Add UIProgressBar to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

I have a requirement to display a `UIProgressBar` in `UITableviewCell` while streaming an audio clip.

I tried running a `NSTimer` and then trying to update the progress view, but its not working. This is my code. Please let me know whats wrong with this approach.

**Run the timer**

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.25
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(updatePlayProgress)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];
```

**Update UIProgressView in TableviewCell**

```
- (void)updatePlayProgress {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSLog(@"Duration %f", appDelegate.moviePlayer.duration);
    NSLog(@"Current time %f", appDelegate.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime);

    float timeLeft = appDelegate.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime/appDelegate.moviePlayer.duration;

    // upate the UIProgress
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:playingIndex inSection:0];
    FeedCell *cell = (FeedCell*)[self tableView:self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"Time left %f", timeLeft);

    cell.progressPlay.progress = 0.5;

    [cell.progressPlay setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

**CellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
fCell.progressPlay.alpha = 0.5;
fCell.progressPlay.tintColor = navigationBarColor;
[fCell.progressPlay setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(fCell.frame.size.width, fCell.frame.size.height)];

[fCell.progressPlay setHidden:NO];

return fCell;
```

Output should be something similar to this

[image]

Comment: Try to have your UITableViewCell as an iVar in your UIViewController. I think your progress is being reset, or at least the value is not persisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found the issue after almost 2 days :( :( 
Error was in this line

**Wrong**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:playingIndex inSection:0];
FeedCell *cell = (FeedCell*)[self tableView:self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

**Corrected**

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:playingIndex inSection:0];
FeedCell *cell = (FeedCell*)[self.tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: So, what is difference between the above two methods ? The both variants call the UITableViewDataSource method cellForRowAtIndexPath. It depends on how you create the cell inside that method.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `[self.tblView reloadData]` you are setting the progress bar back to `0.0` in the following line `fCell.progressPlay.progress = 0.0`. Remove the call to `reloadData`.

Comment: did remove [self.tblView reloadData]. But nothing happens